# Calculating permutations when the set of elements contains "copies"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Say we have a set of people with the same name:

S={A,B,C,C,D,E,F}

They are clearly,different people but two of them have the same name.

To use the permutations formula,it is demanded that the set contains different elements.Perhaps in this example,it shouldn't bother much,but in a situation where the set contains the characters:

S={a,a,b,b}

Can the formula be applied?If not,why?

By definition,sets contain different elements,is there any way to "distinct" the duplicate elements in order to use them at the formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Well the question is: Do you want to have the people or the names in the set? Do you want to permute the names or the people? A name does not determine completely a person, meaning that you can have other characteristics as the representation of the person in the set.

Comment: I get your point,thank you.But what about the example about the set of characters?

Comment: If you mean that the set contains $4$ people and all of them just have two names and you want to order the people, then you will permute all of them $4!$ If you want to permute the names, you will get $4!/(2!\cdot 2!).$Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Could you explain why is it 4!/(2!⋅2!)  about the second case?By the way,the second example was about a set with 4 characters,'a','b' with some repetition,not names

Comment: You ask if the formula can be applied but do not identify the formula you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If a multiset consists of $n_1,n_2,\dots n_k$ indistinguishable objects of distinguishable types $1,2\dots k$, the number of all distinct permutations of the objects is determined by the multinomial coefficient: $$\frac{n!}{\prod_i n_i!},$$
where $n=\sum_i n_i$ is the total number of objects in the multiset.